# steps to get Lognormal and weibull fits in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, normal-distribution, weibull

I  have a set of data, which is plotted below.

```
x=np.array([10,25,50,100,150,200,250,400,500,750,1000])
y=np.array([[8.18330674e-10,1.20275439e-09,1.34761451e-09,1.39233456e-09,
             1.39826787e-09,1.39951392e-09,1.39984821e-09,1.40000430e-09,
             1.40001260e-09,1.40001474e-09,1.40001482e-09]])
```

[Plotted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcEoT.png)

I want to fit a lognormal distribution (and also a weibull fit) to this set of data. I have conducted a good bit of research and still couldn't find how to go about it in Python. For the lognormal, I computed the mean ln(x) and stnd deviation of ln(x) using excel. I have also computed the shape parameter and scale parameter for weibull using excel as well. I want to write a function in python to obtain a fit to this data and thus obtain the scale,shape parameters for my data. Can anyone help?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Comment: scipy (https://www.scipy.org/) has code for fitting many distributions; check out http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscipy%5D+fit+lognormal and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscipy%5D+fit+weibull

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I have tried some of the example codes in the link you provided and got better mean, sigma values. But how do I use them to fit it over my data (which is shown in the edited question). Please help !